# Python Paramiko Dropping End of Data

Tags: python, paramiko

I am new to paramiko and I am using the code below. It returns the data I am looking for most of the time, but then sometimes it will drop the end of the data I need. I am sure this is a dumb error, but I can't figure it out lokking in the docs.

```
import paramiko


nbytes = 4096
hostname = xxx
port = xx
username = xxxxx
password = xxxxx

command "Something I can't post on here, but I have verified it works"

client = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
client.connect(username=username, password=password)


stderr_data = []
session = client.open_channel(kind='session')
session.exec_command(command)

while True:
    if session.recv_ready():
        stderr_data.append(session.recv(nbytes))
    if session.recv_stderr_ready():
        stderr_data.append(session.recv_stderr(nbytes))
    if session.exit_status_ready():
        break
```

Comment: I usually setup an `SSHClient` instead of a transport directly. `SSHClient` sets up transport and channels as necessary. I don't know if this is your problem but it seems odd to setup your own channel this way.

Comment: Block reading is not good idea if haven't any standard length of data.Try : `while session.recv_ready(): stderr_data.append(session.recv(nbytes))`

Comment: Thank you both. adding the recv to the while loop instead of block reading has seemed to do the trick.